# SQL syntax error - SELECT statement within INSERT

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have this line of sql which gives me a syntax error following the closing parenthesis of the select statement. I was under the belief that I could write the code this way. Is there some alternative?

The variables inside the select statement come from GET and the others come from POST. Any help is appreciated.

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO playerRegSeason 
       (playerID, year, teamID, gp, minutes, pts, oreb, dreb, reb, 
        asts, stl, blk, turnover, pf, fga, fgm, fta, ftm, tpa, tpm)
VALUES ((
       SELECT playerID FROM players WHERE firstname='$firstname' 
       AND lastname='$lastname' AND firstseason=$firstseason), $year, 
      '$team', $gp, $minutes, $pts, $oreb, $dreb, $reb, $asts, $stl, 
       $blk, $turnover, $pf, $fga, $fgm, $fta, $ftm, $tpa, $tpm)";
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `VALUES` when you're inserting from a select.

```
INSERT INTO abc (foo, bar)
SELECT x, y FROM z
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO playerRegSeason 
       (playerID, year, teamID, gp, minutes, pts, oreb, dreb, reb, 
        asts, stl, blk, turnover, pf, fga, fgm, fta, ftm, tpa, tpm)

       SELECT playerID, $year, '$team', $gp, $minutes, $pts, $oreb, 
         $dreb, $reb, $asts, $stl, $blk, $turnover, $pf, $fga, $fgm, 
         $fta, $ftm, $tpa, $tpm FROM players WHERE firstname='$firstname' 
       AND lastname='$lastname' AND firstseason=$firstseason";
```

Comment: I get this error:   

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT playerID FROM players WHERE firstname='' AND lastname='' AND firstseason=' at line 2

Comment: @user2884641: check the sample in sql fiddler http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4ef5d/1 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab89e/1

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table1 (field1, field2, ...)
select col1, col2, ...
from table2
where ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement you wrote is incorrect, you need to remove the values clause or you can refer [Insert with select](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) to learn how to write a insert with a select statement

Answer (score 0):

Use this query instead of that one it's working

$sql2="INSERT INTO playerRegSeason (playerID, year, teamID, gp
       ,minutes, pts, oreb, dreb, reb, asts, stl, blk, turnover, pf, fga, fgm, fta, ftm, tpa, tpm)

```
    values(SELECT playerID,year, $team, $gp, $minutes, $pts, $oreb, $dreb, 
    $reb, $asts, $stl, $blk, $turnover, $pf, $fga, $fgm, $fta, $ftm, $tpa, $tpm
    WHERE firstname='$firstname' 
    AND lastname='$lastname' AND firstseason='$firstseason')";
```